# Invalid String initialization for c++

Tags: c++

I was trying to make a script for a math thing that a saw and I got the following error...

> line 23|error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'std::__cxx11::string&' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_string&'} from an rvalue of type 'bool'|

I am pretty new to c++ and I tried to search this problem on the internet, but nothing works. Can you please help me?? (code below btw)

```
#include <string>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

bool hasEnding (std::string &fullString, std::string &ending) {
    if (fullString.length() >= ending.length()) {
        return (0 == fullString.compare (fullString.length() - ending.length(), ending.length(), ending));
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

int main() {
    int current_num;
    bool odd;
    bool even;
    cout << "Type a positive number: "; // Type a number and press enter
    cin >> current_num;
    while (current_num >= 2) {
        std::string s = std::to_string(current_num);
        cout << s << endl;
        odd = hasEnding (s, "1"||"3"||"5"||"7"||"9");
        even = hasEnding (s, "0"||"2"||"4"||"6"||"8");
        if (odd == true) {
            current_num = current_num*3;
            current_num = current_num+1;
        }

        if (even == true) {
            current_num = current_num/2;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect that `"1"||"3"||"5"||"7"||"9"` should be?

Comment: What do you mean by this expression: `"1"||"3"||"5"||"7"||"9"`? In C++ it evaluates to `bool`, hence the compilation error (your function expects `std::string`)

Comment: Looks like you need an array or vector as the second parameter to your functions.

Comment: In `"1"||"3"||"5"||"7"||"9"` initializing  a `std::string` with the bool  true is not what you want.

Comment: BTW, you can test for positive or negative numbers with this expression `(string[index_last_digit] - '0') & 1;`  if the result is zero, the number is even.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the people in the comments... I fixed it by finding a thing that checks if a number in even or odd instead of making a very inefficient script which checks the last number. The solution for it was `n % 2 == 0`